# Another question about comparing paths for directory

Tags: c#, directory, subdirectory

I am trying to compare two path and detect a failing case when the parent step folder is different than it should be. I am coding it in C#. I have two paths that I assigned to these file paths.

Should succeed

```
_slectedPath= :\\AA\\SS\\BB\\CC\\RR\\XXXX"
Value = :\\AA\\SS\\BB\\CC\\RR\\XXXX\\LLL.xml
```

Should fail

```
_selectedPath= :\\AA\\SS\\BB\\CC\\RR\\XXXX"
Value = :\\AA\\SS\\BB\\CC\\RR\\XXXX\\**YYYY**\\LLL.xml
```

What I have tried.

```
if (!value.Contains(_selectedPath))
{
 error(message)
}
if (!_selectedPath.Contains(value))
{
 error(message)
}
if (Path.GetFullPath(value).Equals(Path.GetFullPath(_selectedPath))))
{
 error(message)
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. As C and C# are very different languages, please don't add unrelated tags.

Comment: One has a filename which has to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Try use [Path.GetDirectoryName()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getdirectoryname?view=netframework-4.8) to get the directory name without the file name.